# .submit() and form validation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to sharpen my vanilla JavaScript skills a little bit.  I am working on a form validator just for fun.  Here is my code thus far:

```
var getParent = document.getElementById("myForm");

document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function(e) {

e.preventDefault();

var cache = !cache ? "Nothing has been selected" : cache;

for(i = 0; i < getParent.elements.method.length; i++) {

    if(getParent.elements.method[i].checked) {
        cache = getParent.elements.method[i].value;
    }

}

getParent.submit();

}
```

As you can see, this just tests some radio buttons to see if they are checked or not.  I am trying to use the `.submit()` function at the bottom to submit my form, but I am getting an error.  Why is this code not submitting my form with `.submit()`??

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Property 'submit' of object #<HTMLFormElement> is not a function

Comment: use another ID than "submit" for the button

Comment: altough this question is not related to jQuery, the issue is the same: [Why do i get an exception when I use JQuery's form.Submit() in IE8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848174/why-do-i-get-an-exception-when-i-use-jquerys-form-submit-in-ie8)

Comment: I'd say it's not a duplicate. The question contains a different error message because the actual issue is different: he spelled it `Submit` instead of `submit`. I wouldn't have expected OP to have found that question by Googling the error message, so it's sufficiently different.

Comment: @Dr.Molle Dem kids and their jQuery, I'll tell 'ya. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not have the button named `submit` and use `submit()`.

The button will override the method. So, when you call `getParent.submit()` it actually points to the button, not the actual submit function.

Comment: Some technical detail: forms allow you to access elements of the form by name, e.g., `loginForm.username` returns the `username` input field. So, while forms have a `submit` method by default, if a field named `submit` is present, it'll override the `submit` method. That's why `submit` is "not a function": in this case, it's a button.

Comment: Ahh, thank you sir.  I forgot that we can overwrite methods pretty easily.

Comment: I've always found this "helpful" method of accessing form fields as properties of the form element to be highly intrusive. I get the intent, but it leads to bizarre bugs like this quite often.

Comment: @AlexWayne: It's an artifact of a previous era, when the DOM API was built around very specific tasks like form interaction. If we could get rid of all old websites and start the API from scratch, this feature probably wouldn't make the cut.